# How do you integrate/configure an Apache Http Server with Mule ESB

Tags: apache, http, mule, esb

We currently have mule ESB running on out network. Not in the DMZ.
I'm looking for information on how to configure an Apache Http server running in the DMZ to act as a proxy for a web service running on the ESB.

Thanks

Comment: Have you search for it?

Comment: Yes, I can't find anything in this regard

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP transport of Mule doesn't have any specific requirement in term of headers, so basically there's no particular recommendation for proxying HTTP requests in front of Mule.

So in the case of Apache, use `mod_proxy` to configure a reverse proxy in front of Mule and you should be good.